# Conflicit with Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.beta

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

In the following query for getting events from Outlook Calendar, I am getting the error shown below. The error seems to be complaining about conflicting between two references `Microsoft.Graph` and `Microsoft.Graph.beta`. But I'm not using `Microsoft.Graph.beta` as shown in the `References` section of my Solution Explorer (screenshot below):

**Question**: Why the error and how can we resolve it (other than using `var` data type instead of `IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage` because I am interesting more in investigating the error than just finding a workaround)?

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Providers;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Graph;

IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage events = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request()
        .Select("subject,organizer,start,end")
        .OrderBy("createdDateTime DESC")
        .GetAsync();
```

> > Error CS0433  The type 'IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage' exists in both 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta, Version=0.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=3.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

**Screenshot of VS2019 Solution Explorer**:

[image]

Comment: Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls depends on Microsoft.Graph.beta.

Comment: @JonSkeet So, should I take `Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls` out; or maybe, not reference `Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph` if referencing `Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls`?

Comment: I don't know - I assume you *need* Microsoft.Toolkit.Graph.Controls, or you wouldn't have a reference to it... but we don't really know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed. I should try to see which one I need. I am probably mixing things up while going through different MS Graph tutorials from MS Graph team - such as [Get calendar data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/uwp?tutorial-step=4) and then another one on `OneDrive`. But you have answered the question in the post.